# shortest substring of string in C#

Tags: c#, string

I try to write I program that given a string comprised of lowercase lettes in the range ascii[a-z] and determine the length of the smallest substring that contains all of the letters present on the string.

but I got Terminated due to timeout.

How can I improve the sulotion?

I tried:

```
    public static int shortestSubstring(string s){
        int n = s.Length;
            int max_distinct = max_distinct_char(s, n);
            int minl = n;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    String subs = null;
                    if (i < j)
                        subs = s.Substring(i, s.Length - j);
                    else
                        subs = s.Substring(j, s.Length - i);
                    int subs_lenght = subs.Length;
                    int sub_distinct_char = max_distinct_char(subs, subs_lenght);
                    if (subs_lenght < minl && max_distinct == sub_distinct_char)
                    {
                        minl = subs_lenght;
                    }
                }
            }
            return minl;
    }
        private static int max_distinct_char(String s, int n)
        {
            int[] count = new int[NO_OF_CHARS];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                count[s[i]]++;

            int max_distinct = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < NO_OF_CHARS; i++)
            {
                if (count[i] != 0)
                    max_distinct++;
            }
            return max_distinct;
        }

}
```

Comment: "_got Terminated due to timeout_" What? How? Is there a referee standing behind you, looking over your shoulder while you run your program?

Comment: You already count the number of distinct chars (`max_distinct`) in your input string. Good. So, why would you then let your code extract any sub string from your input string that's smaller than `max_distinct` and execute `max_distinct_char` on those "too-small-to-be-good" sub strings? The CPU is doing much work for no benefit, or...?

Comment: You also don't need to have both `i` and `j` start at zero. What's the point of it? Instead of `i`/`j`, use two nested loops where the outer loop iterates possible start positions for a sub string (you don't need to iterate the start position to the very end of the input string - see my last comment). And the inner loop would iterate possible end positions of the sub string. Possible end positions don't need to start at 0, they _always_ have to be greater than the start position, no? Again, (see previous comment), it should also be easy to avoid/skip usless end positions for your sub strings.

Comment: Generally, before starting to code, develop and exercise the task at hand mentally, perhaps with the help of pen and paper. If you do this mental exercise diligently step-by-step and note any step you yourself do to solve the task, you would quite likely avoid the problems your code exhibits. (compare those steps with what your program currently does, and you should quickly spot where and why your program wastes time on useless work...)

Comment: "ASCII[a-z]": .NET uses the UTF-16 encoding of the Unicode character set. Given the range of expected input, you could consider each UTF-16 code unit (`char`) a complete character, even though, in general, it is not. [`Console.WriteLine("".Length);`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f609/index.htm) A code comment about this would make your algorithm clear.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is an O(n) solution to this problem as follows:

We first traverse the string to find out how many distinct characters are in it. After this, we initialize two pointers denoting the left and right index of the substring to 0. We also keep an array counting the number of each character currently present in the substring. If not all characters are contained, we increase the right pointer in order to get another character. If all characters are contained, we increase the left pointer in order to possibly get a smaller substring. Since either the left or right pointer increase at each step, this algorithm should run in O(n) time.

For inspiration for this algorithm, see [Kadane's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) for the maximum subarray problem.

Unfortunately, I do not know C#. However, I have written a Java solution (which hopefully has similar syntax). I haven't stress tested this rigorously so it's possible I missed an edge case.

```
import java.io.*;
public class allChars {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(shortestSubstring(s));
    }
    public static int shortestSubstring(String s) {
        //If length of string is 0, answer is 0
        if (s.length() == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        int[] charCounts = new int[26];
        //Find number of distinct characters in string
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i ++) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            //If new character (current count of it is 0)
            if (charCounts[c - 97] == 0) {
                //Increase count of distinct characters
                count ++;
                //Increase count of this character to 1
                //Can put inside if statement because don't care if count is greater than 1 here
                //Only care if character is present
                charCounts[c - 97]++;
            }
        }
        int shortestLen = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        charCounts = new int[26];
        //Initialize left and right pointers to 0
        int left = 0;
        int right = 0;
        //Substring already contains first character of string
        int curCount = 1;
        charCounts[s.charAt(0)-97] ++;
        while (Math.max(left,right) < s.length()) {
            //If all distinct characters present
            if (curCount == count) {
                //Update shortest length
                shortestLen = Math.min(right - left + 1, shortestLen);
                //Decrease character count of left character
                charCounts[s.charAt(left) - 97] --;
                //If new count of left character is 0
                if (charCounts[s.charAt(left) - 97] == 0) {
                    //Decrease count of distinct characters
                    curCount --;
                }
                //Increment left pointer to create smaller substring
                left ++;
            }
            //If not all characters present
            else {
                //Increment right pointer to get another character
                right ++;
                //If character is new (old count was 0)
                if (right < s.length() && charCounts[s.charAt(right) - 97]++ == 0) {
                    //Increment distinct character count
                    curCount ++;
                }
            }
        }
        return shortestLen;
    }
}
```

Comment: `new int[Character.MAX_VALUE + 1]` would simplify the code—at the cost of only 256KB.

Comment: In C#, `Char.MaxValue + 1`

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand it right, here's the code to get the smallest string.

```
        string str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec dictum elementum condimentum. Aliquam commodo ipsum enim. Vivamus tincidunt feugiat urna.";
        char[] operators = { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '!', '?', ';' };
        string[] vs = str.Split(operators);
        string shortestWord = vs[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < vs.Length; i++)
        {
            if (vs[i].Length < shortestWord.Length && vs[i] != "" && vs[i] != " ")
            {
                shortestWord = vs[i];
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(shortestWord);
```

Comment: No. The input contains only lower chase letters. The OP is looking for the shortest sub-string containing all the letters contained in the input. E.g. if the input is `"aabbccb"`, then the result would be `"abbc"`, respectively its length `4`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an `O(n^2)` problem. This is not ideal; however, we can do several things to avoid testing sub-strings that cannot be valid candidates.

I suggest to return the sub-string itself, instead of its length. This helps to validate the result.

```
public static string ShortestSubstring(string input)
```

We begin by counting the occurrence of each character in the range  ['a' .. 'z']. We can subtract `'a'` from a character to get its zero-based index.

```
var charCount = new int[26];
foreach (char c in input) {
    charCount[c - 'a']++;
}
```

The shortest possible sub-string is equal to the count of distinct characters in the input.

```
int totalDistinctCharCount = charCount.Where(c => c > 0).Count();
```

To count the number of distinct characters in the sub-string, we need the following Boolean array:

```
var hasCharOccurred = new bool[26];
```

Now, let's test sub-strings starting at different positions. The maximum start position must allow sub-strings at least as long as the `totalDistinctCharCount` (the shortest possible sub-string).

```
string shortest = input;
for (int start = 0; start <= input.Length - totalDistinctCharCount; start++) {
    ...
}
return shortest;
```

Inside this loop we have another loop counting the distinct characters of the sub-string. Note that we work directly on the input string to avoid creating a lot of new strings. We only need to test sub-strings that are shorter than any shortest one found before. Therefore the inner loop uses `Math.Min(input.Length, start + shortest.Length - 1)` as limit. Content of loop (in place of the `...` in the upper code snippet):

```
    int distinctCharCount = 0;
    // No need to go past the length the previously found shortest.
    for (int i = start; i < Math.Min(input.Length, start + shortest.Length - 1); i++) {
        int chIndex = input[i] - 'a';
        if (!hasCharOccurred[chIndex]) {
            hasCharOccurred[chIndex] = true;
            distinctCharCount++;
            if (distinctCharCount == totalDistinctCharCount) {
                shortest = input.Substring(start, i - start + 1);
                break; // Found a shorter one, exit this inner loop.
            }
        }
    }

    // We cannot omit characters occurring only once
    if (charCount[input[start] - 'a'] == 1) {
        break; // Start cannot go beyond this point.
    }

    // Clear hasCharOccurred, to avoid creating a new array evey time.
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        hasCharOccurred[i] = false;
    }
```

A further optimization is that we stop as soon as we encounter a character at the start position occurring only once in the input string (`charCount[input[start] - 'a'] == 1`). Since every distinct character of the input must be present in the sub-string, this one must be part of the sub-string.

---

We can print the result in the console with

```
string shortest = ShortestSubstring(TestString);
Console.WriteLine($"Shortest, Length = {shortest.Length}, \"{shortest}\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program program = new Program();
        int totalStudent = 3;
        int totalSubject = 5;
        int[,] marks = {{75,76,65,87,87},
                        {78,76,68,56,89},
                        {67,87,78,77,65}};

        string firstString = "this is a test string";
        string secondString = "tist";

        program.Shortest(firstString, secondString);

    }

    public void Shortest(string input1, string input2)
    {
        int minLength = input1.Length;
        string smallestSubstring = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < input1.Length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = i; j < input1.Length; j++)
            {
                string substr = input1.Substring(i, j - i + 1);
                if (ContainsAllCharacters(substr, input2))
                {
                    int currentLength = substr.Length;
                    if (currentLength < minLength)
                    {
                        minLength = currentLength;
                        smallestSubstring = substr;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(smallestSubstring);

    }

    private bool ContainsAllCharacters(string input1, string input2) 
    {
        int[] count = new int[256];

        // Count the frequency of each character in the pattern
        foreach (char ch in input2)
            count[ch]++;

        // For each character in the substring, decrement its
        // count
        foreach (char ch in input1)
        {
            if (count[ch] > 0)
                count[ch]--;
        }

        // If all counts in the count array are zero, the
        // substring contains all characters of the pattern
        foreach (int val in count)
        {
            if (val > 0)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```